# How to split multiple strings from one column into separate rows and replace it with value from other table based on mapping between 2 tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Suppose i have one table in which data is like in below format

```
user  count  string  type_string
TEST     3    A B C   ooo
TEST1    4    D EF G  oooo
```

i want output into below format

```
user  string 
TEST     A
TEST     B
TEST     C
TEST1    D
TEST1    E
TEST1    F
TEST1    G
```

after that we have one more table in below format which has mapping of above string like in below format

```
mapping   mapping1
A           AA
A           AB
A           AC
B           BC
B           BR
C           CC
C           ED
C           LL
D           EE
D           TT
E           RT
F           FG
G           GG
G           OP
```

so i want to replace the mapping value of string value from first table in below format like

```
user  string 
TEST     AA
TEST     AB
TEST     AC
TEST     BC
TEST     BR
TEST     CC
TEST     ED 
TEST     LL  and so on
```

Comment: I don't understand how you get to that last result. Is it `SELECT iwantoutput.user, onemoretable.mapping1 INNER JOIN onemoretable.mapping = iwantoutput.string` to get that result?

Answer (score 0):

Solving for the first part you can use `unnest` and `string_to_array` like so:

```
SELECT user, unnest(string_to_array(replace(string, ' ', ''), NULL)) as string
FROM yourtable;
```

That will give you your results like:

```
user  string 
TEST     A
TEST     B
TEST     C
TEST1    D
TEST1    E
TEST1    F
TEST1    G
```

It's not clear how you derive your final desired result set, but it feels like a simple inner join will do the trick.